# Film identification: Two men using equipment to play metal CD-like discs

Tags: story-identification, movie

I remember seeing a film (or part of) a long time ago (probably about 1988) and I'm trying to identify it. As I recall it was black and white. The only bit of it I remember had two men working with some equipment, trying to get it to work. The equipment was for playing discs (something like CDs, but I think they were metal). When they got it working it projected the image and sound of a third man. I can't recall if the image was purely a recording, or if it could interact with the other men and respond to them. There might have been an element of time travel in the film as well, or I could be mixing it up with something else. The film was in English (not dubbed / subtitled).

Thinking a little more about it I think that the person on the recordings was the boss of the other two and was issuing them their orders.

#### UPDATE

I seem to recall that there were lots of discs (in a heap on the floor?) and that the one they needed had a scratch on it. I think the machine might have been outside - they might have been on another planet perhaps?

Comment: Only commenting this as it's almost definitely wrong, but there was a film adaption of H.G Wells' "The Time Machine", (which added many bits in) where the main characters listened to spinning discs/CD's that had endured over thousands of years- although you probably would have mentioned the nuclear blasts etc. That also featured in the war... It was in colour though, so probably not what you're looking for.

Comment: @MikasaPinata Thanks, I had thought it was possibly `The Time Machine` as I know I watched that when I was young, but from reading some detailed plot summaries it didn't sound right. I guess I'll just have to watch it and make sure!

Comment: @MikasaPinata I found a clip about the part you were talking about and unfortunately it's definitely not what I'm looking for. I think the person on the recordings was the boss of the other two and was issuing them their orders.

Comment: Sorry about that! Hope you find the movie, it's annoying when you can't place something. Good luck for future hunters!

Answer (score 5):

I'm thinking This Island Earth (1955).  they assemble a machine they know nothing about and use a metal disc to contact the alien Exeter who entices them to work for him.
[image]

Comment: That looks promising, I'll have to see if I can find a copy. Thanks.

Comment: @Eborbob - I remember seeing this movie, and I believe it matches what you're looking for.

Comment: The movie is available on youtube at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pG7h3sWnBIU . It's a pretty bad quality version but you might be able to confirm the answer there.  The disk scene is about 15 minutes in.

Comment: Just watched those few minutes on YouTube and it's a perfect fit for the description I gave. Unfortunately it doesn't seem right - I don't think it's the film I'm after! Thanks for the suggestion though.